# Upgrading Apache Open Office

Tags: installation, downloads

I have downloaded the Apache OpenOffice upgrade 4 times. Once downloaded a window opens with lists asking me if I want to open a doc or extract it. I highlighted all of the OpenOffice lines and got a message that they were all extracted. Then a window came up asking me where the program could be found. How should I know?
At any rate my Apache OpenOffice is not upgraded and I have no idea how to get the download into the current OpenOffice program.

This is probably basic stuff, but I often download programs that never show up on the desktop bar or desktop so I can use them. My download file has tons of programs I have downloaded and never saw again. Some of them have codes instead of names, so I do not recognize them to extract. No matter, I seldom know what to do after the extraction anyway. What do you suppose I am leaving undone?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to learn how to install packages that you downloaded from the internet and possibly may even require compiling, you should install your applications from the default Ubuntu repositories whenever possible. Just because you can't find an application to do a specific job in the default Ubuntu repositories doesn't mean that a suitable application is not there. In fact it usually *is* there. You just have to know how to search for it. The technical phrase that is used to describe this is "software recommendation".

Regarding Apache OpenOffice, you should stick to the default LibreOffice that comes with the default Ubuntu install. It is very nearly 100% compatible with OpenOffice in every way, and receives its updates in the usual way through Software Updates.

Finally, if you have to install a file that you downloaded that has a .deb extension, just double-click on it to install it using the Ubuntu Software Center. If the file that you downloaded has a .tar.gz extension, you will have to open it with Archive Manager and look for a README file in the archive where the instructions for installing the package are usually found.

Answer (score 0):

User,

Karel is basically right on all counts. That is, your default LibreOffice should be able to open any document/spreadsheet/presentation, etc. that Apache OpenOffice can, and pretty much operates the way you are used to with what is now called Apache OpenOffice (AOO). The new OpenOffice maintainers just released v4.0, so I understand why you might want to try it out.

I will guess that you selected the Linux Intel DEB (for 32-bit computers) or the Linux x86-64 DEB package from the table listed here: http://www.openoffice.org/download/other.html. Note: If your computer was made before 2009, use the "Intel DEB" version; if it's newer, use the "x86-64 DEB." If you're not sure, use the "Intel DEB," because newer machines can run the 32-bit, but 32-bit machines can't run 64-bit.

The Apache folks have complicated the download and install package process, by wrapping the DEB package in a tar.gz archive. So, as karel suggests, you first have to open the file with Archive Manager first, extract the DEB from the archive, then (finally) double-click the DEB. Ubuntu Software Center should then be able to install AOO safely.

Whenever possible, use the Ubuntu Software Center to get interesting new programs. It will save you a ton of time and heartache.